# Vídeos do youtube em app

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

Como incorporar um vídeo do meu canal do *YouTube* a um app em *iOS*?

Segui [esse guia](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) do *YouTube Developers*, mas o vídeo não aparece na tela.

Meu [código](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64NioIEb-GsUnhGcllOaVZOXzQ/view?usp=sharing) está assim:

## FirstViewController.h

```
//
//  FirstViewController.h
//  GaleRio
//
//  Created by Alex on 25/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Creapix Tecnologia Criativa. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "YTPlayerView.h"


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController


@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;

@end
```

## FirstViewController.m

```
//FirstViewController.m
//  GaleRio
//
//  Created by Alex on 25/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Creapix Tecnologia Criativa. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FirstViewController.h"


@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE"];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

As ligações no storyboard foram feitas corretamente, acho que o problema esta no *ID* do vídeo no youtube.

**EDIT:** Tentei a [solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43452/3907) do [Lucas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15056/lucas-eduardo) mais não adiantou.

<sub>**Nota:** código disponível na íntegra [aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64NioIEb-GsUnhGcllOaVZOXzQ/view?usp=sharing).</sub>

Comment: a ligação entre o teu IBOutlet e a classe esta bem feita?

Comment: A solução proposta por mim não funcionou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou apenas incluir o arquivo `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` dentro do Diretório `Assets` usando a opção *Create folder references* como descrito [na documentação](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

O passo mencionado pelo [Lucas Eduardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15056/lucas-eduardo) é opcional para que funcione.